# Unit testing InfoPath form C# code behind

Tags: c#, unit-testing, infopath

Does anyone know a decent way of unit testing the InfoPath FormCode of browser-enabled InfoPath Form Templates that submit data via web services? I can call the public methods from an external test project and mock some of the classes in a way of passing the data sources into the methods, but I cant seem to isolate them easily. The FormCode class cannot be inherited from and it inherits from XmlFormXostItem class which has the MainDataSource, NamespaceManager, etc properties without a setter, so I can`t easily implement my own and have the FormCode instance use them in my tests. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just discovered that Microsoft Fakes can shim pretty much anything, so that gets me moving forward for now.